# How to trade for an unusual hat in TF2

Tags: steam, team-fortress-2

I have some spare keys that I want to trade for an unusual hat.

What are the prices of all the unusual hats? And is there an unusual within the price range of 5-10 keys?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no definite answer to this question. There aren't "prices" on hats in TF2, people can ask for whatever they want

Comment: @JoethePerson Just because its a barter economy doesn't mean that there are not prices and established exchanges. You can ask whatever you want in real life too, but prices still exist, and there are entire websites dedicated to hat prices.

Answer (score 2):

There are entire dedicated websites for this and thousands of unusuals, nobody is making a full list for this here, plus the prices are constantly changing so it would not be acceptable for this site.

TF2 hat pricing information is available at a number of websites, including tf2spreadsheet.blogspot.com/, backpack.tf/pricelist‎, and tf2unusual.com.

For unusuals in particular check out backpack.tf/unusuals. Based on that site, even the cheapest unusuals run 10-15 keys, and most are expensive enough to be measured in earbuds.

Comment: OMG they are expensive as heck. Btw how do you get earbuds. are they uncratable or can they be dropped with a rare drop?

Comment: @FdaYak No, they are a specific popular item that was awarded to TF2 Mac players in 2010. You can only get them by trading now which is why they hold their value so well to be used as currency